# JPA JPQL Query on optional ManyToOne attribute

Tags: java, sql, jpa

My entity has a nullable ManyToOne association to second entity.  I am building a UI with a single search box, and I'd like to include rows where the search matches fields from the parent, or the child entity.

Right now this looks something like:

```
@Entity
public class RequestForm {
  ...

  @ManyToOne 
  @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", nullable = true, updatable = false, insertable = false)
  private Company company

  ...
}
```

And I'm querying like this:

```
    Query q = em.createQuery("select req from RequestForm req where 
                + "( "
                + "(req.id like :query) "
                + "or (upper(req.name) like :query) "
                + "or (req.companyId is not null and upper(req.company.companyName) like :query) "                  
                + ")", RequestForm.class);
       q.setParameter("query", "%" + query.toUpperCase() + "%");
```

When I include the req.company.companyName in my query, JPA builds the SQL in a way that only returns rows where the ManyToOne exists.  When the user searches for example 'Sam', I'd like to return rows where RequestForm.name contains Sam or RequestForm.Company.name contains Sam.  What I get is only rows where RequestForm.company.name contains 'Sam'.  If RequestForm.name contains 'Sam' but there's no Company, or Company.name doesn't match 'Sam' they aren't returned.  Any suggestions?  Am I just approaching this problem the wrong way?

Comment: The company column at the table is named 'company' ? if not you must specify a column to make the join with @JoinColumn

Comment: The join seems to be working correctly.  I was trying to post some simplified code and left out the @JoinColumn.  I'll edit my question to include it.